# Objective-C get tile positions from CCTMXTiledMap (Cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to make a simple loop that goes over all the tiles in the CCTMXLayer in the CCTMXTiledMap. All I want to achieve is to print out the position of every single tile, but for the life of me i can't figure out how to loop through the tiles or how to even get access to their container. I am a objective-c newbie, so please be gentle :)

Please halp!

What I have so far:

```
CGSize mapSize = [_tileMap mapSize];
CCTMXLayer *backgroundLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];
int h = 0;
int w = 0;
NSInteger i = 0;
for(h = 0; h < mapSize.height; h++)
{
    for(w = 0; w < mapSize.width; w++)
    {
        i = h * mapSize.width + w;
        // I tried the following but none of it worked:
        //CCArray* tiles = [backgroundLayer  children];
        //CCSprite *tile = [backgroundLayer tileAt:tileCoord];
        //CCSprite*tile = [tiles objectAtIndex:i];
        //CCNode* tile = [backgroundLayer children getChildByTag:i];
        CGPoint position = [tile position];
        [_debugHud addTileId:i at:position];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCSprite *tile = [backgroundLayer tileAt:tileCoord];` should work fine, assuming `tileCoord = CGPointMake(h,w);` or something similar.

Are you sure your `CCTMXLayer *backgroundLayer` is not `nil` and is the correct layer?

Comment: i am not sure honestly, still trying to work the xcode. From what i see it doesn't look null. 

Question about "tileAt:tileCoord", the coordinates are not tile indecies, it's actual position, right? as in i could not use the for loops above to go through the tiles?

Comment: The coordinates ARE tile indicies, and the above loops you wrote are actually just fine! CCTMXTiledMap.mapSize is the map's size in tiles, not pixels or points. From CCTMXTiledMap.h: 
`/** the map's size property measured in tiles */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) CGSize mapSize;
/** the tiles's size property measured in pixels */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) CGSize tileSize;`

Comment: omg haha,no wonder nobody else asks this question, thanks! appreciated!

Comment: make sure you check CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR! you'll have o divide by 2 on hose.